# ExtJs bubble menu event

Tags: extjs

I have my ExtJs menu defined as follows. I have two custom methods added to my menu item 'hookMethod' and 'handlerMethod'. 'hookMethod' is added based upon some condition. I bubble the click event for individual menu items to the root menu. 
Then checks if hook is defined then call 'hookMethod' else call the 'handlerMethod' directly. The problem that I am facing is that the click listener is called twice, once for menuitem and once for menu. Also, what is e argument. I was thinking it will be called only once for menu and I will have some way to retrieve the actual menu item being clicked in it.

```
{
    xtype: "menu",
    listeners: {
        click: function(item, e, eopts)
        {
            if(item.hookMethod) { 
                item.hookMethod(item.handlerMethod);
            }
                else {
               item.handlerMethod(this);
            }
         }
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: "menuitem",
        text: "Process Record",
        bubbleEvents: ['click'],
        hookMethod: function(actualMethod)
        {
            //do some pre-processing here and then call the actual handler
            actualMethod(args)
        },
        handlerMethod: function(args)
        {
            //Do actual processing
        },
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ext.menu.Menu` [`click( menu, item, e, eOpts )`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-event-click) event have four parameters.

First parameter is `menu` object itself.

Second `item` parameter is object of the menu item that was clicked. This parameter you can use for determine which item in menu was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why it is being invoked twice? Also 4 parameters(menu, item, e, eopts) are present only on the second invoke. But on the first invoke it has 3 parameters(item, e, eopts).

Comment: This is because you have in your item configuration `bubbleEvents: ['click'],`. So first caught event comes from `menuitem` and second caught event comes from `menu` itself. So remove your `bubbleEvents` configuration and just listen for `menu` `click` event.

Comment: Thanks it worked. However, I thought if I will bubble it up, it won't cause the click on menuitem?

Comment: In `bubbleEvents` config you can just set events which will be bubbled to any parent container. So then your listener for `click` event configured on `menu` component caught both events - bubbled `click` event from `menuitem` component and `click` event from `menu` component